# JDBC Replication driver always returning same data without active cache

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, replication

I am using the MySQL JDBC Replication Driver `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` to shift load between Master and Slave.

I am using that connection URL

```
jdbc.de.url=jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave1:3306,slave2:3306/myDatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8&roundRobinLoadBalance=true
```

As soon as I am starting my application I am getting only that data from where it has been started, like I am working on a locked snapshot of the database. If I am doing any CRUD operation the data is not callable or updates are not shown. Replication of mysql is working just fine and I can query the correct data from the database.

There is no level2 cache active and I am using hibernate with pooled connections

If I am using the normal JDBC Driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` everything is working just fine. So why am I getting always the same resultsets, no matter what I do change in the database...

### Update 1

It seems like it is related to my aspect

```
@Aspect
public class ReadOnlyConnectionInterceptor implements Ordered {

private class ReadOnly implements ReturningWork<Object> {

    ProceedingJoinPoint pjp;

    public ReadOnly(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        this.pjp = pjp;
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

        boolean autoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
        boolean readOnly = connection.isReadOnly();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            connection.setReadOnly(true);
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            //if an exception was raised, return it
            return e;
        } finally {
            // restore state
            connection.setReadOnly(readOnly);
            connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
        }

    }

}

private int order;

private EntityManager entityManager;

public void setOrder(int order) {
    this.order = order;
}

@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return order;
}

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Around("@annotation(readOnlyConnection)")
public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
        ReadOnlyConnection readOnlyConnection) throws Throwable {
    Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Object result = hibernateSession.doReturningWork(new ReadOnly(pjp));
    if (result == null) {
        return result;
    }
    //If the returned object extends Throwable, throw it
    if (Throwable.class.isAssignableFrom(result.getClass())) {
        throw (Throwable) result;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

I annotate all my readOnly request with `@ReadOnlyConnection`. Before I had all my service layer methods annotated with that even though they might be calling each other. Now I am only annotating the request method and I am to the state, where I am getting the database updates on the *second* call.

1) Doing initial call => getting data as expected

2) Changing data in the database

3) Doing same call again => getting the exact same data from the first call

4) Doing same call again => getting the changed data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` is that it seems to not do a commit after set back to `connection.setAutoCommit(true)`. So after adding the following line to the aspect, everything worked as expected again

```
try {
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    connection.setReadOnly(true);
    return pjp.proceed();
} catch (Throwable e) {
    return e;
} finally {
    // restore state
    connection.commit(); // THIS LINE
    connection.setReadOnly(readOnly);
    connection.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
}
```